# graphviz cluster's label multiple lines

Tags: python, label, graphviz, multiline

I'm using python+graphviz in order to create networking topologies out of the information contained in Racktables. I've succeded pretty well so far but I'm willing now to add multiple lines labels to a cluster (not a node).

For example, I have the following code with python:

```
for router in routers:
   [...]
   cluster_name = "cluster"+str(i)
   router_label=router_name+"\n"+router_hw
   c = gv.Graph(cluster_name)
   c.body.append('label='+router_label)
```

When ever I run that program, I get the following:

```
ST120_CMS70_SARM
SARM
ST202_P9J70_SARM
SARM
Error: node "SARM" is contained in two non-comparable clusters "cluster1" and "cluster0"
```

But, if I change this `router_label=router_name+"\n"+router_hw` to this `router_label=router_name+"_"+router_hw`, I get no error and the topology gets drawn, but, of course, a one line label.

Any hint on this?

Many thanks!

Lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution. The multiline label is achieved using HTML like labels, like the following one...

```
router_label="<"+router_name+"<BR />"+router_ip+">"
c = gv.Graph(cluster_name)
c.body.append('label='+router_label)
```

This code provides the following:

[image]

Thanks!

Lucas